# Cannot read property toggle of undefined in one place, but works in another

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a way to expand some content if someone clicks on the title. At first spot I had to "highlight" the clicked elements as kind of a "shopping list". I did this by applying a class and worked perfectly.

At second spot I am supposed to click on an h3 element that will then expand an div element that has almost same name by also applying a class. I will show example below but problem becomes that for some reason everything is undefined.

I thought maybe the reason a crucial variable was undefined is because the code executes before the HTML loads, so I wrapped it inside `window.onload`, this did work on first place but not second.

First place, WORKING

```html
       <button class="btn-shop" id="almonds">Almonds</button>
       <button class="btn-shop" id="apple">Apple</button>
       <button class="btn-shop" id="argula">Argula</button>
```

```
window.onload = function(){
    var ingredientsArray = document.querySelectorAll("#almonds, 
    #argula, #apple");
    ingredientsArray.forEach(function(element){
        element.addEventListener("click", function(){
            element.classList.toggle("active-shop");
        });
    });
};
```

Second Place, NOT working

```html
       <h3 id="reps">Reps</h3>
       <div class="reps-toggle noshow">
              <p>aaaaaaaaaaa</p>
       </div>
       <h3 id="timeinterval">Time Interval</h3>
       <div class="timeinterval-toggle noshow">
              <p>aaaaaa</p>
       </div>
```

```
window.onload = function(){
    var trainingType = document.querySelectorAll("#reps, #timeinterval, 
    #tabata");
    trainingType.forEach(function(element){
        element.addEventListener("click", function(){
            var elementAndToggle = element + "-toggle";
            elementAndToggle.classList.toggle("noshow");
        });
    });
```

Complete error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined at HTMLHeadingElement. (script.js:6)

Tried console.logging some of the variables.
All the values are undefined, `trainingType`, `element`, `elementAndToggle`. I dont' understand why.

I would like to not only have solution but, for someone kind to explain to me what the problem was and how this works so I can learn and not make same mistake again.

Comment: `elementAndToggle` is a string.  Strings do not have a `classList` property.  Set a breakpoint on that line.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense, unfortunately i didnt understand what you mean by set a breakpoint on that line. Would you mind helping me out a bit?

Thanks for quick response.

Comment: Specifically, doing `element + "-toggle"` does not work in a meaningful way. It produces a string like `"[object HTMLElement]-toggle"`.

Comment: @randomSoul That doesn't matter; `toggle` will add the class even if none exist...

Comment: I do know that, but thats why i tried to make another variable that contains the id`s name + the toggle extension. Which will become the name of the class in that other element. Wouldnt that work?

Comment: @FilipHrnjez Google the name of your browser and "how to set breakpoints".  Knowing how to use a debugger is an essential skill for development.  It is worth taking the time to learn.

Comment: @FilipHrnjez The issue is that your `forEach` isn't retrieving a list of *`id` values*-- it's retrieving of list of *DOM elements* matching the selector. To get the id value of each element, you need to retrieve the `.id` attribute of the `HTMLElement`, as I've detailed in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `elementAndToggle` variable.

Within `trainingType.forEach`, you refer to each element in the page matching your `querySelectorAll`. Immediately after that, you set the value of `elementAndToggle` to *the element itself*, and concatenate a string to it. This causes the variable's value to become a string like `[object HTMLElement]-toggle`.

It looks like you're trying to retrieve the `id` of each element, append something to it, then query a similar element based on its class. You can do this with:

```
var elementAndToggle = element.id + "-toggle";
document.getElementsByClassName(elementAndToggle)[0].classList.toggle("noshow");
```

Comment: @HereticMonkey Prepending the period just seems like more effort than it's worth given that there's a built-in method already. It's a matter of opinion.

Comment: This worked, thanks alot. Would you please explain to me why 
document.getElementsByClassName(elementAndToggle)[0].classList.toggle("noshow"); worked but not elementAndToggle.classList.toggle("noshow");

Comment: Of course. I've laid out exactly what's going on above and in my comment on your question. `element` is a *DOM Element*-- that is, it is an `object` that refers to the element on the page (e.g., `<div id="almonds"></div>`). What you actually want is the `id` attribute of the element, which is a *string* (e.g., `almonds`).

Comment: Thanks alot. Shouldve just asked here at once, been breaking my head around for some time now :P

Comment: No worries. It's always good to try on your own first, and when that doesn't work, we're here to help :)